# Need help in displaying the advertisement banner in drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal-6

I Am Facing The Problem That in drupal 6.20 website Made .Currently We are Using Ad & Area Banner Module in the website .When we add the banner from the Admin then the Ads are displayed on all the Pages of the Website . The website is Very Large and there are almost 1,000 of Pages in the website .
But The Client is saying That if i select a Particular page from the Admin then the Ads should be displayed on that particular Page only .
But The Banner Displayed on All the Pages of the Websites
Searched on the Internet but There is no Module Available.

How should I Proceed in this situation?

Is there we have to create our own module ?
if Yes
How we should Proceed or else there is Any Shortcut way of doing this ?

Thanks for Your Valuable Time .

Help for this will be highly appreciated .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not putting the banner in a block?

You can modify the pages in your block where it is visible.

By modifying your theme you can create new block sections/regions and put your banner where you want.